# Dismissing a viewcontroller messes up the content of UIScrollView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview, scroll

I have FirstViewController which contants a UIView with a UIScrollView in it and there's a UITableView in the UIScrollView. The UITableView has scrolling disabled and I only increase the contentSize of the UIScrollView to be able to see the complete UITableView.

```
___________________________________
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
-----------Various content---------
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
___________________________________
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|           UITableView           |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|_________________________________|
```

When I'm at a point in my UIScrollView so that the contentOffset =/= 0 and I press a cell in the UITableView I modally present a new controller (SecondViewController). This works fine. When I dismiss the SecondViewController the content in the FirstViewController is messed up.

The UITableView is initially set to have it's origin in the middle of the screen (vertically). When I dismiss the SecondViewController the UITableView sure has it's origin in the middle of the screen but the content that's above the UITableView is pushed up within the UIScrollVIew with value of contentOffset (what it was before pushing SecondViewController).

```
___________________________________
|                                 |
-----------Various content---------
|                                 |    
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |    
|                                 |
___________________________________
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|           UITableView           |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
|_________________________________|
```

EDIT: I just discovered that the _startOffsetY in the UIScrollView is changed. And I don't know if this has anything to do with it but paging is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this :

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];


}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, scrollSubView.frame.size.height))];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are using iOS5 simulator or device because dismiss model viewController is deprecated in iOS6.

To work in all iOS you have to present like....

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
{
    [self presentViewController:test animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else
{
     [self presentModalViewController:test animated:YES];
}
```

and dismiss like

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)])
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:animated completion:nil];
}
else
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}
```

Hope you will like this............